# Fabric: passing different arguments to each task?

Tags: python, fabric

I have the following CSV:

```
ip, arg1, arg2
1.2.3.4, foo, bar
1.3.4.5, baz, bub
```

I am trying to perform:

1. For each row in the CSV: ssh into the ip specificed,
2. Execute commands such as `apt-get` with arg1 for that row
3. Execute custom commands that will utilize arg2 for that row

Fabric has `execute(do_work, hosts=host_list)` but I can't really specify the right context for that. So far, I have hacked together something:

```
from fabric.api import env, execute

arguments = {}


def _deploy():
  print env.host_string, arguments[env.host_string]


def deploy():
  global arguments
  arguments['1.2.3.4'] = ('foo', 'bar')
  arguments['2.3.4.5'] = ('baz', 'bub')
  execute(_deploy, hosts=arguments.keys())
```

This is printed:

```
[1.2.3.4] Executing task '_deploy'
1.2.3.4 ('foo', 'bar')
[2.3.4.5] Executing task '_deploy'
2.3.4.5 ('baz', 'bub')
```

Currently, this hasn't broken anything. Is there a better way or even a better lib for me to do this?

**Note: I am not a fan of paramiko because it's too low level.**

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant *per se*, but this is the solution that I am settling with:

```
def special_echo(matrix):
  key = 'ubuntu@' + env.host
  name = matrix[key]
  run('echo %s `hostname --ip-address`' % name)

A = {}
A['ubuntu@54.219.171.62'] = 'first'
A['ubuntu@52.53.149.140'] = 'second'
A['ubuntu@54.183.255.58'] = 'third'

execute(special_echo, A, hosts=A.keys())
```

---

Results in:

```
[ubuntu@54.219.171.62] Executing task 'special_echo'
[ubuntu@54.219.171.62] run: echo first `hostname --ip-address`
[ubuntu@54.219.171.62] out: first 172.31.1.234
[ubuntu@54.219.171.62] out:

[ubuntu@54.183.255.58] Executing task 'special_echo'
[ubuntu@54.183.255.58] run: echo third `hostname --ip-address`
[ubuntu@54.183.255.58] out: third 172.31.15.36
[ubuntu@54.183.255.58] out:

[ubuntu@52.53.149.140] Executing task 'special_echo'
[ubuntu@52.53.149.140] run: echo second `hostname --ip-address`
[ubuntu@52.53.149.140] out: second 172.31.8.138
[ubuntu@52.53.149.140] out:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an edge case in fabric that comes up from time to time.  I can show you a strategy I've used in the past, but I'll start on a safer variation of your strategy.

The env dictionary is designed to store environment data that can be used by other tasks.  Any data that should be shared between tasks but that cannot be passed as arguments can go here, so I'd change your code to keep arguments in env:

```
from fabric.api import env, execute, task

def _deploy():
    print env.host_string, env.arguments[env.host_string]

@task
def deploy():
    env.arguments = {}
    env.arguments['1.2.3.4'] = ('foo', 'bar')
    env.arguments['2.3.4.5'] = ('baz', 'bub')
    execute(_deploy, hosts=env.arguments.keys())
```

The second strategy is one that I've used myself in the past to perform work like this and involves passing all arguments as part of the host string and letting the task be responsible for parsing that in to usable data.  It keeps you from passing a large dictionary around globally, and with your use-case might be effective:

hosts.csv

```
1.2.3.4, foo, bar
1.3.4.5, baz, bub
1.4.5.6, complex-args, maybe with spaces
```

fabfile.py

```
from fabric.api import env, execute, run, settings, task

def _parse_args(argument_string):
    # you should really use the csv module here to split properly (escapes, etc)
    args = argument_string.split(', ')
    if len(args) != 3:
        raise ValueError("Only the host and 2 arguments are allowed")
    return args

def _deploy():
    host, arg1, arg2 = _parse_args(env.host_string)
    with settings(host_string=host):
        # run("apt-get '{}'".format(arg1))
        # run("service '{}' restart".format(arg2)
        print "[{}] apt-get '{}'".format(env.host_string, arg1)
        print "[{}] service '{}' restart".format(env.host_string, arg2)

@task
def deploy():
    with open('hosts.csv') as f:
        hosts = [ line.strip() for line in f ]
    execute(_deploy, hosts=hosts)
```

Here's the output you'd see using this strategy:

```
$ fab deploy
[1.2.3.4, foo, bar] Executing task '_deploy'
[1.2.3.4] apt-get 'foo'
[1.2.3.4] service 'bar' restart
[1.3.4.5, baz, bub] Executing task '_deploy'
[1.3.4.5] apt-get 'baz'
[1.3.4.5] service 'bub' restart
[1.4.5.6, complex-args, maybe with spaces] Executing task '_deploy'
[1.4.5.6] apt-get 'complex-args'
[1.4.5.6] service 'maybe with spaces' restart

Done.
```

Comment: @Sparrowcide that would only be the case if you overrode env.  The default implementation supports attribute access: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/state.py#L334

EDIT: Whoops, you're right.  I never defined it as a dictionary.  I've updated the example.  That's my bad.